# Confidence interval of functional - R code

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

**Question 1** - Generate 200 data points from the random variable $X \sim exp(2)$, and construct a 95% CI for the functional $\theta=E[e^{X}]$.

My R code is as follows:

```
x <- rexp(200, rate=1/2)
theta.hat <- mean(exp(x))
sigma.hat <- sd(exp(x))
error <- qnorm(0.975)*sigma.hat/sqrt(200)
left <- theta.hat-error
right <- theta.hat+error
```

Then (left,right) is a 95% confidence interval for $\theta$. Is this confidence interval correct?

**Question 2** - Make a simulation with N=1000 data samples to check what the confidence intervals covering probability is.

My R code is as follows:

```
N <- 1000
count <- 0
          for(i in (1:N)){
            x <- rexp(200,rate=1/2)
            theta.hat <- mean(exp(x))
            sigma.hat <- sd(exp(x))
            error <- qnorm(0.975)*sigma.hat/sqrt(200)
            left <- theta.hat-error
            right <- theta.hat+error
            count <- count+as.double(left<=2 & 2<=right)}
count/N
```

However after running the code a few times count/N returns values $\approx 0.76$. I was expecting values $\approx 0.95$? Have I made a mistake or am I missing something?

Comment: Your second code snippet does not define n, I assume it is set elsewhere to be 200? (Also, if you suspect this is actually a programming issue, then this is the wrong stack exchange for the job.)

Comment: Getting back to mathematical matters, notice that $e^X$ has finite mean but not finite variance.

Comment: @Ian  I corrected the second code snippet. I did weight posting on another stack exchange as you mention but I "suspect" that the problem/mistake is of a mathematical nature which you have indeed pointed out. Thanks, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for but it might help you understanding what is going on.

You could get a $95\%$ confidence interval in three different ways:
(1) Monte Carlo
(2) Calculate the distribution of $e^X$ and the distribution of the mean of $e^X$
(3) Central Limit Theorem

You used the third one in question 1. However, as Ian noted, the variance is not finite. In that case, you cannot use it because, well, the variance is infinite. Moreover, you estimated the variance with the sample variance but, in general, it is better if you could plug in the actual variance there if you know how to calculate that one. Furthermore, you found out in Question 2 that the covering probability is not close to $.95$ and this is thus due to the statistical error that is introduced when the Central Limit Theorem is used.

I haven't tried the second method here and I don't know whether it is possible to do it exactly (I don't think it is, to be honest). But in general this might be useful if, for example, when the mean is distributed according to a known distribution (such that you can calculate the parameters).

Last but definitely not least, you can always approximate the distribution of the mean of $e^X$ using Monte Carlo methods, which is the first option I gave and essentially your solution is Question 2.

I hope this is what you're looking for. If some details are unclear, feel free to comment!

Comment: Nice answer: (+1) Estimates of $\theta$ will have an extremely right-skewed distribution. I interpret your (1) to mean that for a 95% CI one should try to simulate quantiles .025 and .975 of that distribution. (This dist'n doesn't have a variance, but it does have those quantiles). With R code `y=replicate(10^6,mean(exp(rexp(200,1/2)))); quantile(y,c(.025,.975))` I got CI $(63.1,\; 320,000).$ Taking logs: $(4.14, 12.6).$ Several runs of a million iterations agree to 3 signif digits. // Is this what you meant to suggest? If not, can you clarify where this does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what I meant. My simulations yield approximately the same results (although I don't see why you want to take the logarithm). Moreover, I see that indeed you need approximately a million repetitions to get 'stable' results.